# In what sequence (and how ) does rpy2 finds R on a Windows system?

Tags: python-3.x, rpy2

How does rpy2 searches for installed R on a Windows system and in what sequence does it go through each (say PATH, registry etc.)?

Version of rpy2 I am using is 3.4.4 on python 3.7

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/blob/624a0aca031c73c0126e070910b6865419d0de63/rpy2/situation.py#L153

Comment: This what I was looking for. Thanks @Axe319